# Oozie Sqoop Job

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I'm trying to run sqoop job as oozie action. I have MySQL as a metastore on the jobtracker node. I read somewhere that oozie sqoop cannot create hive tables from import. So I'm trying to dump the data in to hdfs. Is that still true ?

I checked the share libs.

I'm trying to Sqoop from a MS SQL database.

When I run sqoop command which doesn't need a meta store from shell it works.

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://host;username=sqoopimport;password=password;database=db1' --table t1--target-dir /user/root/sqoop-import/tmp/t1
```

When I try to run this as sqoop action I get this error

```
    >>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

2151 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
2259 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
2285 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: 'jdbc:sqlserver://host;username=sqoopimport;password=password;database=db1'
at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:185)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:217)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.init(ImportTool.java:83)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:464)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:203)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:172)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:495)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

workflow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="sqoop-wf">
    <start to="sqoop-node"/>

    <action name="sqoop-node">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
             <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                 <property>
             <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
             <value>true</value>
           </property>
           <property>
             <name>oozie.libpath</name>
             <value>/user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop</value>
           </property>
            </configuration>
            <command>import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://host;username=sqoopimport;password=password;database=db1' --table t1--target-dir /user/root/sqoop-import/tmp/t1</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I think this is the main reason. I have the libs in share lib directory
    2285 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string:

Am I missing something ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are executing Sqoop using shell (for example Bash or ZSH), you need to manually escape the arguments, so that the shell won't alter them. In your example you've put the JDBC URL into quotes, so that the semicolon won't be interpreted as end of the command. As Oozie is not using shell for calling Sqoop, those escape characters are not valid. Therefore you should remove the escaping introduced for the shell in the oozie workflow.

E.g:

```
<command>import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://host;username=sqoopimport;password=password;database=db1 --table t1--target-dir /user/root/sqoop-import/tmp/t1</command>
```

Also please note that it's recommended to use the arguments --username and --password instead of the same named properties in JDBC URL.

Answer (score 0):

try giving `--driver com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` in your arguments> Also make sure you have MS SQL Server JDBC jar present in the classpath.